# Calculate the values of the serieses

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-analysis

Given this function: $f(x)=|\sin x|$, I was supposed to find its cosinuses series, which came out $$\frac{2}{\pi}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4}{\pi\left(1-4k^2\right)}\cos(2kx)\,.$$
After that, I was asked to find the values of these two serieses:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4n^2-1}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{\left(4n^2-1\right)^2}$$
Using Parseval Theorem, I got to this:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(4k^2-1\right)^2}=\frac{3\pi^2}{16}-\frac{1}{2}$$
but I don’t know what to do next…

Comment: This is difficult to read. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Amazona, if you apply Parseval theorem correctly, you will get that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(4k^2-1\right)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac{1}{2}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;\displaystyle 0=f(0)=\frac{2}{\pi}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4}{\pi\left(1-4k^2\right)}\,,\;$ it follows that

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4}{\pi\left(4k^2-1\right)}=\frac2\pi\;\;,$

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{4k^2-1}=\frac12\;.$

Hence,

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4n^2-1}=\frac12\;.$

Moreover, by using Parseval Theorem, we can get that :

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(4k^2-1\right)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac{1}{2}\;.$

Consequently ,

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{\left(4n^2-1\right)^2}= \frac14\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4n^2-1}{\left(4n^2-1\right)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\left(4n^2-1\right)^2}\right]=$

$\displaystyle= \frac14\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4n^2-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\left(4n^2-1\right)^2}\right]=$

$=\dfrac14\left(\dfrac12+\dfrac{\pi^2}{16}-\dfrac12\right)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{64}\;.$

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! So parseval wasn't needed after all...

Comment: @Amazona, you need Parseval theorem to calculate the second series inside of the square brackets.

Comment: @Amazona, $\frac{2}{\pi}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4}{\pi\left(1-4k^2\right)}\cos(2kx)\,$ is the cosinuses series of the function $f(x)=|\sin x|$. Absolutely, it is **not** the cosinuses series of $f(x)=\sin x+1$.